# CodeIgniter - Cannot validate form in view to javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

I have file .js in this link: C:\xampp\htdocs\ab-group\assets\js\default.js

I've made a form and I wanna validate it. I also already linked the js file in HTML head but it doesn't work.
I use a same way in calling css file and it succeeded, but why I can't call js file?

here my view code:

```
<head>
 <title>Welcome to AB Group</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/default.css')?>"
  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(). "assets/js/default.js" ?>"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-style-3">
    <form id="form_sendEmail" name="form_sendEmail" method="post" onsubmit="validate();">
        <fieldset><legend>Personal</legend>
            <label for="field1"><span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="name" id="name" value="" /></label>
            <label for="field2"><span>Email <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="email" class="input-field" name="email" id="email" value="" /></label>
            <label for="field3"><span>Phone <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="phone" id="phone" value="" /></label>
            <label for="field4"><span>Subject</span><select name="field4" class="select-field">
                <option value="Information">Information</option>
                <option value="Complain">Complain</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select></label>
            <label for="field5"><span>Shipment Code <span class="optional"></span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="field5" value="" /></label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset><legend>Message</legend>
            <label for="field6"><span>Message <span class="required">*</span></span><textarea name="message"  id="message" class="textarea-field"></textarea></label>
            <label><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" onclick="validate()" id="sendEmail" value="Send Email" /></label>
            <span class="required">* Indicates Required Field</span>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

and here my js file:

```
    $(document).submit(function () {
function validate()
{
     var emailID = document.form_sendEmail.Email.value;
     atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
     dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");

     if( document.form_sendEmail.Name.value == "" )
     {
        alert( "Please provide your name!" );
        document.form_sendEmail.Name.focus() ;
        return false;
     }

     if( document.form_sendEmail.Email.value == "" )
     {
        alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
        document.form_sendEmail.Email.focus() ;
        return false;
     }else if(atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 ))
     {
         alert("Please enter correct email ID")
         document.form_sendEmail.EMail.focus() ;
         return false;
     }

      if( document.form_sendEmail.Phone.value == "" )
     {
        alert( "Please provide your phone number!" );
        document.form_sendEmail.Phone.focus() ;
        return false;
     }

      if( document.form_sendEmail.Message.value == "" )
     {
        alert( "Please write your message!" );
        document.form_sendEmail.Message.focus() ;
        return false;
     }else{
        return( true );
     }
}
});
```

I hope js file could validate the form is empty or not and validate email as well. Please help to find a mistake in my code. Thank you very much.

Comment: check in the console if it is getting `default.js` file or not

Comment: yes, it gets default.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change `$(document).submit(function ()...` to become `$(document).ready(function()...` and then (somehow) it works.

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be at linking js file. So try this.

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?> assets/js/default.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry, I've edit it as your answer above but it still doesn't work.

Comment: See on console of browser by inspecting. If problem is in js file  then you can see actual error. also try this <script src="<?php echo base_url(). 'assets/js/default.js' ?>"></script>

Comment: After I check the console. I find some errors and I've fixed it (I already updated my code above). But well... the validation is still not work.